# "In included file: 'stddef.h' file not found" In CodeLite 15.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: c++, linux

**Disclaimer** The only programming experience I have is with Arduino and I wanted to get into full on C++ coding so I got an IDE and all that jazz.

I'm running into this issue and I have no idea what to do. I've been scouring Google for hours. I've tried everything I can find and I finally decided to make an account here.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Build Output:

```
MESSAGE: Entering directory `/home/user/Dev/HelloWorld'
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -f/home/user/Dev/HelloWorld/Makefile -j 8'
----------Building project:[ HelloWorld - Debug ]----------
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/src/Main.cpp.o
c++: error: Werror: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/src/Main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [/home/user/Dev/HelloWorld/Makefile:84: all] Error 2
====0 errors, 0 warnings====
```

Run Output (In terminal):

```
/home/user/.codelite/tmp/user/codelite-exec.sh: line 3: /home/user/Dev/HelloWorld/HelloWorld: No such file or directory
Hit any key to continue...
```

CMakeLists.txt contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (HelloWorld)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall - Werror -std=c++14")
set (source_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/")

file (GLOB source_files "${source_dir}/*.cpp")

add_executable (HelloWorld ${source_files})
```

CodeLite error:

```
In included file: 'stddef.h' file not found
/usr/include/wchar.h:35:10:
note: error occurred here
```

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: Code should work, so something's gone wrong in the building process. Please add the full build output to the question. Not sure where they hide that in codelite, but it'll probably be in a tab at the bottom just like everyone else does.

Comment: Alright I added the info I think you all want

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the `CMakeLists.txt`. Publish it.

Comment: Try to compile directly from the terminal.

Comment: Alright, I added the requested file. I tried compiling in terminal and It worked

Comment: There is no mention of stddef.h in the included messages.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. I'll add a screenshot

Comment: Please do not add screenshots.

Comment: `- Werror` - the space looks wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks that's working now. I feel a bit silly

Comment: Ok so basically my code all compiles fine but CodeLite is still showing red arrows all over. I am including the error messages in an edit currently

Comment: You probably need to configure CodeLite and tell it where to find header files. `stddef.h` is compiler-specific, and CodeLite has no idea where to find compiler-specific headers. Something like `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include` should do the trick (you should use your gcc version of course).